# Put tab headers in their own grid row?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl inside a Grid. Is there a way to assign the tab "headers area" to fill a particular grid row, and the tab content area to fill another?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Without writing your own control, I don't think this is something possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like @xtreampb pointed out, you will need to make some modifications if you truly want to separate the functionality out.

HOWEVER, you do have multiple options to accomplish this if you don't want to dig through the control templates. For example, the last time I had to facilitate such a request I only had about 15 minutes to do it. So what I ended up doing was like the concept shown below and just made a `RadioButton` style to match the design of the "Tabs" they wanted.

Was quick and painless (under 5 minutes) and served the purpose at the time. Plus the app was really small and the owner's didn't care about much else than the design they wanted.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20">
      <RadioButton GroupName="Blah" Content="Blah1" 
                   IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=Blah1}"/>
      <RadioButton GroupName="Blah" Content="Blah2" Margin="10,0"
                   IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=Blah2}"/>
      <RadioButton GroupName="Blah" Content="Blah3" 
                   IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=Blah3}"/>
   </StackPanel>

   <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
      <TabItem x:Name="Blah1" Visibility="Collapsed">
         <TextBlock Text="Wow TAB 1 IsSelected!"/>
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem x:Name="Blah2" Visibility="Collapsed">
         <TextBlock Text="Wow TAB 2 IsSelected!"/>
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem x:Name="Blah3" Visibility="Collapsed">
         <TextBlock Text="Wow TAB 3 IsSelected!"/>
      </TabItem>
   </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: I like it, though my actual product dynamically creates tabs from a collection, binding the tabs into existence via ItemsSource. That makes things harder. I'm currently looking into styling the control's TabPanel size to mimic the row height.

Comment: @JVimes Ya I've gone and made the RadioButton trick into an ItemTemplate for ItemsControl before and just incremented the names on stuff++ to match the items.count on something else before....but that's when things had to be entirely separated both visually and logically. Are you literally just needing the headers to match a certain size row? If that's all you actually need, makes things much easier.

Comment: That's my current task. While not the focus of this question, how to do that would be a good aside to the answer, which sounds like "basically, no" ;)

Comment: @JVimes Hah, ya it's "basically, no" as to the easy separation of Header and the Panels....but, the actual Header just sits inside the TabItem style template with a `ContentPresenter` with `ContentSource` set to "Header", the `TabPanel` is what brings that into the TabControl, you just grab that style and and you can bind in or stretch the Height to whatever you like be it the parent or specific size.